# Если прямая речь с тире открывается ремаркой, где место тире?

Tags: пунктуация

> – Какую бы ты поставила себе оценку за предмет «постельное двоеборье»
>   –  по десятибалльной шкале?
>
> – *(После паузы.)* Двенадцать. *(Смеется.)* Спросите кого хотите!

Из другого места интервью:

> – Какая у тебя была самая большая разница в возрасте между тобой и
>   партнером?
>
> – *(Считает.)* Двадцать лет. Конечно, всё зависит от конкретного
>   человека, но юные мужчины меня не интересуют.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо, тире на месте.

Если бы это была пьеса, был бы обозначен носитель реплики, точка, ремарка в скобках, текст реплики.

В диалогах художественного текста ремарку развернули бы в вводящие слова автора:

*Она медленно считает и говорит:*

*– Двадцать лет.*

В интервью, по-моему, ремарку только выделяют курсивом. Диалогическое тире должно показать, чья реплика. Видимо, оно же указывает и на  обращённость ремарки, так что всё верно: тире, ремарка, реплика.